# Piggy Sentence python translator

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program to replace words in a sentence, translating into Pig Latin (teacher doesnt care about vowels, only capitalization) I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the code I've written.

```
def PiggySentence():
    sentence=str(input("Please enter the sentence you would like converted 
    to Pig Latin: "))
    sentence.split()
    caps ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    for word in sentence:
        if word[0] in caps:
            word = word[1].upper() + word[2:] + word[0].lower() + "ay"

        else:
            word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"

    sentence = " ".join(sentence)
    print(sentence)




PiggySentence()
```

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 18, in <module>
    PiggySentence()
   line 7, in PiggySentence
    word = word[1].upper() + word[2:] + word[0].lower() + "ay"
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: "I can't seem to get it to work" is not a problem description. Please specify the behaviour you expect and the one you're actually observing.

Comment: added error message, thank you.

Comment: Consider trying each word[] reference on a separate line to see which one is causing the error.

Comment: It is not a good idea to mix your loop variable (word) with your algorithm. Then your code assumes that every word input has at least 2 char and every word that starts with a upper case letter has at least 3 char (probably the root cause of the error)

Comment: If you include a word with just a single capital letter, you will get that error. You need to handle words that are just one character long.

Comment: All great feedback, thanks!

Comment: Also, `sentence.split()` returns a list of words, but you are ignoring that return. You probably meant: `sentence = sentence.split()`.

Comment: Add an if statement checking the length of the word before you start indexing it. `if len(word) > 0: ...`

Answer (score 1):

1. The issue here is that `word[2]` is out of range, meaning the string is not long enough to have a third character. I'm not sure how you want your program to handle small words like `a`, whether you want to skip them or just append a `ay` or something else.
2. In your loop, setting `word` is not modifying the original array. You may want to have an ouput variable that you can add your translated words to, for example:

```
output = []
for word in sentence:
    if word[0] in caps:
        output.append(word[1].upper() + word[2:] + word[0].lower() + "ay")

    else:
        output.append(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay")

sentence = " ".join(output)
```

3. Putting `sentence.split()` on a separate line doesn't do what you want it to, as it just returns the array split at every character. You want to store the return value after splitting it at every space, so you want to do `sentence = sentence.split(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't be taking input inside a function.
Second, you are not considering single letter words.
modify your function to do the Pig Latin formatting only if the length is greater than one.

Something like this.

```
def PiggySentence():
sentence=str(input("Please enter the sentence you would like converted to Pig Latin: "))
sentence.split()
caps ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
for word in sentence:
    if len(word) > 1:
        if word[0] in caps:
            word = word[1].upper() + word[2:] + word[0].lower() + "ay"

        else:
            word = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"

sentence = " ".join(sentence)
print(sentence)
```